# Replace bbcode with strings to html in database

Tags: html, mysql, replace, bbcode

Is there any way to search and replace bbcodes to html like this:

```
[youtube:2w378626]HXmiAW2coOs[/youtube:2w378626]
```

to this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/?v=HXmiAW2coOs
```

using phpmyadmin or a php script?

Thank you in advance,

Ed.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at the PEAR package [BBCode Parser 2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_BBCodeParser2). 
PECL also has one similar to the PEAR version: [BBCode Parser](http://pecl.php.net/package/bbcode)

Comment: Hi AJeneral, thank you for your help. I'm reading the BBCode Parser 2 page but it looks like its way beyond my limited knowledge and server permissions on my hosting provider (hostgator). I have a copy on my XAAMP installation on my Mac, so I'll check what would I need to use this locally. Best regards, Ed.